# Why copy & paste dart2js' output to console doesn't work?

Tags: dart, dart2js

compile the following code with `dart2js -o test.js test.dart`

open `test.js`, copy its content

open browser, go to stackoverflow.com

open dev tools, go to console tab

paste `test.js`'s content into console, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

I expect it to click the "Ask Question" button, but it doesn't, why?

(The reason I want to do this is, I need some js, but I don't want to touch js.)

```dart
// test.dart
import 'dart:html';
void main() {
  document.querySelector('#nav-askquestion').click();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't dig very deep but I had the impression the generated code registers itself for a script loaded event and then executes "main" as event handler. I don't know JavaScript and browser behavior good enough to understand how this can work.

I got it working by running this code in the dev console

```js
(function runTest() {
  var s = document.createElement("script");
  s.type = "text/javascript";
  s.src = "test.js";
  document.body.appendChild(s);}
)();
```

where the `test.js` (generated output from `dart2js`) file is in the same directory as the `index.html`.

The code adds the script tag referencing the `dart2js` output dynamically and the code in `test.js` is executed.